# Hello world. Первая программа на  Perl

Tags: active-perl, cmd, perl

Как открыть текст программы и где его писать? Нажал пуск>выполнить>cmd и дальше не знаю что делать.
Ну прогу в блокноте написать могу, а как ее запустить, и как пользоваться эктив перл, вот в этом у меня вопрос )

Comment: Just another perl hacker надо писать, hello world это не кошерно.

Comment: Спасибо Void, но никак не могу сохранить на диске С, и выводит фигню смд, решил что с андроидовского телефа писать будет проще, т.к. комп не мой )
Страдаю над игрой «жизнь», вопрос выше.

Comment: Ну не можете на C (возможно, нет прав на запись в корень диска), так сохраните на D, или в директорию, куда есть права записывать, например C:\Users\Artem. Только вот потом cmd наберите perl "C:\Users\Artem\test.pl" и будет счастье.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Скачать сам Perl непосредственно, можно прямо [отсюда](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads).
- Установить его. Я думаю, справитесь. Если не уверены в выборе компонентов, просто жмите кнопки "Далее". И так до конца. В итоге у вас появится папка С:\Perl, куда, собственно он установится по умолчанию. Это просто для информации - в папку лезть не надо.
- Откройте Notepad. Сохраните файл как **test.pl** (для этого в диалоге сохранения в графе **Save As type** выберите **All Files**, а в строчке выше замените ***.txt** на **test.pl**. Файл сохраните на **С:**, т.е. в корневой директории диска. Notepad не закрывайте.
- Наберите в открытом **test.pl**, который у вас открыт в Notepad-е, следующие строки:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/perl  
  print "Hello World!\n";  
  sleep(5);
  ```
- Сохраните файл еще раз.
- Затем выполняете *Start -> Run -> cmd*. Затем **Enter**.
- В появившемся черном окне введите *cd \* и нажмите **Enter**. Затем наберите *perl test.pl* и нажмите **Enter**.
- Наслаждайтесь результатом и начинайте разбираться с этих азов, которые вам дают прямое представление о том, как это работает.

Comment: Вот эта строчка мне больше всего нравится:

     #!/usr/bin/perl

И нет у него ни /usr, ни /usr/bin, и perl живёт где-то в другом месте...

Comment: Да пофиг. Под windows достаточно, чтобы perl.exe был в PATH. Для запуска под апачем это может быть важно, но это уже вторая ступень Силы :-)

Comment: @alexlz - это-то понятно, но автор вопроса - начинающий. Наше дело - помочь в начинании, так сказать, указать на правильный путь. Тем более правила хорошего тона рекомендуют оформлять скрипты с заглавной упомянутой строки, неважно, что используется Windows :)

Comment: Похоже у нас разные правила хорошего тона. Мне не нравится, что человеку приходится следовать бессмысленным ритуалам. В unix-like'ах эта строка вполне осмысленна, а в виндах -- увы. Ещё интереснее получается, когда она осмысленна частично (Кажется в *.tcl в виндах можно упрятывать совершенно разные скипты, поскольку tclsh/wish эту строчку интерпретируют). Но всё это -- потом. А так д.б. "правило грибов" -- "не знаешь -- не бери".

Comment: Дело не в подходе, а в том, что автора, я надеюсь, заинтересовало бы наличие этой строки, и, возможно, он бы попытался бы понять, собственно зачем эта строка нужна. Почитал бы про *nix,сравнил бы и т.д. Вот, читая наши комменты, он уже заинтересовался скорее всего, с чего такой сыр-бор по поводу первой строки :)

Comment: Заинтересовать школьников в изучении географии, задав вопрос: "А вы сможете натянуть презерватив на глобус?"

Comment: Заинтересовать школьников в изучении географии, задав вопрос: "А вы сможете натянуть презерватив на глобус?" Пхахахахаха!XD

Тут такая проблемка, что я не могу сохранить на диске С. И при открытии смд и далее как вы говорили, пишет фигню, решил проблему с помощью планшета, т.к. за компом крайне редко сижу.

Comment: Ну так сохраните на диске D. Куда сохранять - дело второстепенное.

Answer (score 1):

Писать в любом редакторе. Запускать "perl myscript.pl" (впрочем, есть вещи типа EPIC - Perl Editor and IDE for Eclipse, в которых можно и редактировать, и зпускать, и отлаживать)

Comment: Ну по-моему, activeperl при установке создаёт в реестре ассоциацию .pl (а также .pls и пр.) с perl.exe. Так что можно запустить из проводника (или что там в w7), только могут быть проблемы с просмотром результатов, если окно закроется.

Comment: Как запускать  "perl myscript.pl"?

Comment: Набрать это на клавиатуре (без кавычек) и нажать Enter.

Answer (score 0):

Установил `activeperl`, написал `HTA` файл с `perl`-скриптом и Ваше приложение готово! И `cmd` не нужно. Хотя можно и просто `html` использовать. `Perl` может через `ODBC` обращаться к базам данных, например, `Ms Access`, причем, и довольно шустро, и по локальной сети, так что и приложение уже написать можно доброе.

Comment: "так что и приложение уже написать можно доброе"

Увы, если на перле, то не доброе, а злое.

Comment: @alexlz чем вам так перл не угодил ?

Comment: Когда-то мне приходилось на нём писать и _читать_ . Былые ощущения оживают быстро. Слабо (если вообще) типизированный язык с неоднозначным синтаксисом. Одна сосуществующая пара систем видимости чего стоит. А недавнее обсуждение оператора `=>`. Да много чего.

А проще -- старею, вопросы надёжности выходят на первый план. А перл -- "лень, гордыня и нетерпение" ((c) L. Wall). Ежели не путаю

Comment: О как. По моему загнули немного :)